# Regular Expression: Two words in any order but with a string between?

Tags: regex

I want to use positive lookaheads so that RegEx will pick up two words from two different sets in any order, but with a string between them of length 1 to 20 that is always in the middle.

It also is already case insensitive, allow for any number of characters including 0 before the first word found and the same after the second word found - I am unsure if it is more correct to terminate in $.

Without the any order matching I am so far as:

```
(?i:.*(new|launch|releas)+.{1,20}(product1|product2)+.*)
```

I have attempted to add any order matching with the following but it only picks up the first word:

```
(?i:.*(?=new|launch|releas)+.{1,20}(?=product1|product2)+.*)
```

I thought perhaps this was because of the +.{1,20} in the middle but I am unsure how it could work if I add this to both sets instead, as for instance this could cause a problem if the first word is the very first part of the source text it is parsing, and so no character before it.

I have seen example where \b is used for lookaheads but that also seems like it may cause a problem as I want it to match when the first word is at the start of the source text but also when it is not.

How should I edit my RegEx here please?

Comment: Hi ! regex patterns alone are indigestible ;) But, sometimes, with a sample data set to work on, everything becomes clear ^^

Comment: Use alternation, `(new|launch|releas).{1,20}(product1|product2)|(product1|product2).{1,20}(new|launch|releas)`